# The level of inconsistency in the Place Autocomplete address_components is high and how am a developer supposed to handle it?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I read and testing the [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) on Android. I understand that the `address_components` below never garantis that types are consistent. The `formatted_address` at the bottom of the code sample here I wonder why it say `USA` since `USA` is not in the `address_components` . Who is or how is the `formatted_address` created?

From the docs:

> formatted_address is a string containing the human-readable address of this place. Often this address is equivalent to the "postal address," which sometimes differs from country to country. This address is generally composed of one or more address_component fields.

USA??

Lets say I want the postal address in the `formatted_address` of the geocode result and depend on it to be correct, now since the `address_components` types never [garantis](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) any type what about the `formatted_address` . Who is or how is the `formatted_address` created? and what garantis does it have?

```
placeDetails = {PlaceDetails@14740} 
 address_components = {ArrayList@14760}  size = 9
  0 = {AddressComponent@14773} "AddressComponent{long_name='5', short_name='5', types=[STREET_NUMBER]}"
  1 = {AddressComponent@14774} "AddressComponent{long_name='Starbird Avenue', short_name='Starbird Ave', types=[ROUTE]}"
  2 = {AddressComponent@14775} "AddressComponent{long_name='Lower Washington / Mount Hope', short_name='Lower Washington / Mount Hope', types=[NEIGHBORHOOD, POLITICAL]}"
  3 = {AddressComponent@14776} "AddressComponent{long_name='Boston', short_name='Boston', types=[LOCALITY, POLITICAL]}"
  4 = {AddressComponent@14777} "AddressComponent{long_name='Suffolk County', short_name='Suffolk County', types=[ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2, POLITICAL]}"
  5 = {AddressComponent@14778} "AddressComponent{long_name='Massachusetts', short_name='MA', types=[ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1, POLITICAL]}"
  6 = {AddressComponent@14741} "AddressComponent{long_name='United States', short_name='US', types=[COUNTRY, POLITICAL]}"
  7 = {AddressComponent@14779} "AddressComponent{long_name='02131', short_name='02131', types=[POSTAL_CODE]}"
  8 = {AddressComponent@14780} "AddressComponent{long_name='3138', short_name='3138', types=[POSTAL_CODE_SUFFIX]}"
 alt_ids = null
 formatted_address = "5 Starbird Ave, Boston, MA 02131, USA"
```

Lets say trough code I take the `formatted_address` and run it trough the `address_components` to filter out lets say the country. The level of inconsistency in the `address_components` is high and how am a developer supposed to handle it?

Why is `address_components` type  `POSTAL_TOWN` sometimes used in a country and sometimes not. I believe this is by design but why the inconsistency?

There´s so many questions about this and for me the importen one is if the `formatted_address` postal address can be trusted to not change?

Comment: I have the same question. It's too confusing.